# Form HTML + Ajax com Jquery e PHP

Tags: jquery, html

Eu tenho um formulário que tem um campo data nativo do HTML5 e preciso que no evento OnChange desse campo data ou seja da troca do valor da data ele chame uma página Php que irá carregar a minha página.

Exemplo do meu código html:

```
<form id="formulario" method="GET">
    <input type="date" name="minhadataatual"/>
</form>
```

Como configurar o Jquery e o Ajax e como receber a data no PHP.
Minhas únicas dúvidas são essas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui fica uma sugestão:

```js
$('input[name="minhadataatual"]').on('change', function(e) {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/url/para/ficheiro.php',
    method: 'GET', // ou POST
    data: {
      // os dados a enviar 
      minhadataatual: this.value
    }, 
    success: function(resposta) { // função corrida no sucesso do ajax
      alert(resposta);
    }
  });
});
```

O ajax é chamado no evento `change` e envia para o PHP um `GET` com `minhadataatual`. No PHP podes fazer:

```
$data = $_GET['minhadataatual'];
```